# Macs on wireless network can't see eachother

Tags: network

I've got an iMac and Macbook Pro, both running Snow Leopard and both on my home wireless network (running off a Linksys E2000). They both can get online fine, both have file sharing enabled, neither have a firewall enabled, and they both have IPs on the same subnet (192.168.1.144 & 146). Yet neither one can seem to see the other. If I open the network browser in Finder it's empty, attempts to go to the other machines IP directly fail after a long timeout, and even trying to ping the other machine fails. Yet, strangely, I've been able to get services like Synergy working just fine between them. Any ideas as to why these two machines are so inconsistent about talking to eachother?

Comment: Snow leopard likes ipv6 for bonjour in snow leopard. Have you turned that off in either network pref pane or on the router.  Also, try pinging host.local as you shouldn't need an ip or dns with a local suffix added ton the short name.

Comment: Pinging <hostname>.local fails from the other machine, unfortunately. As for the IPv6 stuff, I hadn't thought of that before, but upon some investigation it looks like my router (the aforementioned E2000) doesn't support IPv6 unless you flash it with 3rd party firmware like DD-WRT. (Really, Cisco? Really?) I've been considering doing that for a while anyway, so this may be a good excuse, but should I really have to have IPv6 for file sharing? That seems a bit extreme.

Comment: Even if the router doesn't know how to route IPv6 (i.e. to the outside world), it should still be able to bridge it between computers on the private network (whether wired or wireless).  At that level, it's all just ethernet frames, so they'd almost have to go out of their way to break it...

Comment: Wow - if pinging a local host fails, I would temporarily use an Ethernet cable between the two macs to ensure it's not software/firewall or configuration issue before digging into the router.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I can ping localhost in any of it's various forms. (I'd be REALLY worried if I couldn't!) I can't ping the other machine with any address, though, wether I'm using it's IP directly or the appropriate .local name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is really random and bizarre but after a *second* power-cycle of my router suddenly everything started talking again, good as new! I'm honestly pretty stumped by what happened here, and annoyed that this didn't resolve itself on the *first* power-cycle I tried, but all's well that ends well I guess.

If anything I'm sorry that I didn't come out of this with better advice for people with the same problem down the road. Good luck, future network debuggers, 'cause I don't have any advice for you! :P

Comment: LOL, so typical. I would estimate that roughly half of the network issues I have seen people stumped by are fixed by simple reboots/power cycling. I suggest you mark this as the accepted answer since it fixed your problem and is a good reminder to everyone with network problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same setup except that I have an E3000 but I'm not running Synergy.  My Macs can ping each other and share files.  I have IPV6 turned off.  You may have tried some of my suggestions but let see if any of them will help the cause.

I have file sharing enabled on both Macs and I can see my other on-net mac in the Finder Sidebar under Shared.  My Sidebar Preference under Shared allows connected servers and Bonjour computers.  With these settings, can either Finder see the other Mac?  It's good to verify this on both machines as a control.  If you can see either machine, you should be able to double-click to log in.

If not, please turn off Synergy then reboot each mac and see what comes up in Finder.

Make sure your E2000 basic wireless is set to mixed.

I did not use Cisco Connect opting to configure my E3000 manually and I'm not running WPS (WiFi Protected Setup).  If you are running WPS, temporarily disable it to rule it out as a potential cause.  On my E3000, I have configured any MAC access lists and access point isolation is disabled.

Temporarily disable any security option under Wireless Security for both the 2.4G and the 5G settings.

Save router settings.

Reboot each mac and see what comes up in Finder.  This will help us see if this is a Mac, Synergy or Cisco issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with a Linksys E2000 router... the Macs on WiFi could ping the router, an iPad, Linux machines and various infrastructure but could not ping each other and could not be pinged from anything else. This was despite OSX Firewall being turned OFF.

According to Wireless>>Advanced Wireless Settings the AP Isolation option was Disabled. Just for a laugh I Enabled it, Saved Settings, Disabled it again and Saved Settings. Lo and behold the Macs could ping each other and could be pinged by everything else.

Hope this helps someone else.